# Displaying Linked List in order with asterisk at the current position

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to display a circular linked list in order. I know circular list technically don't have a start but I'm thinking of the node that was added first as the start. I have that done. I simply created a temporary reference that referenced the first node and then transversed the list.

However, I also need to display an asterisk at the "current position", which is the node referenced by the reference "cur".

Of course I could start with cur, print an asterisk and circle around the list from there but that wouldn't print the list in order. Is there a way to see what references are referencing a node/address? Or a simpler way to do this?

```
public void displayList(){
        Node temp = this.getHead();

        System.out.print(" ~ ");

        for(int i = 0; i < this.getListLength(); i++){
            System.out.print(temp.getId() + "/" + temp.getTicks() + "/" + temp.getName() + " ~ ");
            temp = temp.getLink();//advance temp
        }

        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Where is `cur` ? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Its declared elsewhere in the List class. It doesn't really matter where it references so I didn't think it was relevant to post it, but I can post the entire List and Node classes if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to literally check the references, you can try to compare the nodes using `node == cur`

However, it may be safer to define an `equals()` method in your Node class and using that method to compare the nodes: `cur.equals(node)`. Depending on your problem/implementation of equals(), this may be misleading (ex: multiple nodes having the same data but different indexes) so make sure to write tests!

Comment: Ah well that makes things simple because the nodes already have id's so I can just write a equals method like you said that compares id's. Thanks. :)